# How to retrieve associated products for configurable product with Magento SOAP API2?

Tags: java, magento, soap

I'm trying to get all the associated products for a configurable product using the Magento SOAP API v2. The catalogProductLink call looks close, but doesn't handle configurable types. I don't see any other calls that contain the associated product and configurable type information for a product. How have others solved this issue?

I'm using Magento version 1.6 and the SOAP API V2 with Java.

Comment: As far as i know for Magento Community v1.6 it doesn't have the handle to retrieve what you wanted.

You must create customized API v2 for this case.

Comment: Josua Marcel - please could you elaborate? If it is possible using a custom API what would the PHP code look like?  I have tried a similar Java API client as above, with both 'related' and 'grouped' both return empty list though I can see the products in the admin client.

Answer (score 1):

I looked deeper into this solution and realized that you may need to override the API model (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api) to achieve the results you're looking for.

In the items function (around line 90), you can do something like this:

```
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $childProductIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($product->getId());
    $result[] = array(
        'product_id' => $product->getId(),
        'sku'        => $product->getSku(),
        'name'       => $product->getName(),
        'set'        => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
        'type'       => $product->getTypeId(),
        'category_ids' => $product->getCategoryIds(),
        'website_ids'  => $product->getWebsiteIds(),
        'children'  => $childProductIds[0],
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- create the folder app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Link
- copy the app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Link/Api.php into this folder and edit it. (I’ve only done the change for the V1 but I’m pretty sure it’s as easy in V2)
- replace the content of the the items() function with the following

  ```
      if($type == "associated"){
      $product = $this->_initProduct($productId);
      try
      {
          $result = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$product);
      }
      catch (Exception $e)
      {
          $this->_fault('data_invalid', Mage::helper('catalog')->__('The product is not configurable.'));
      }

  }
  else
  {
      $typeId = $this->_getTypeId($type);

      $product = $this->_initProduct($productId, $identifierType);

      $link = $product->getLinkInstance()
          ->setLinkTypeId($typeId);

      $collection = $this->_initCollection($link, $product);

      $result = array();

      foreach ($collection as $linkedProduct) {
          $row = array(
              'product_id' => $linkedProduct->getId(),
              'type'       => $linkedProduct->getTypeId(),
              'set'        => $linkedProduct->getAttributeSetId(),
              'sku'        => $linkedProduct->getSku()
          );

          foreach ($link->getAttributes() as $attribute) {
              $row[$attribute['code']] = $linkedProduct->getData($attribute['code']);
          }

          $result[] = $row;
      }
  }
  return $result;
  ```
- then you can call the API like this now:

  $client->call($sessionId, 'product_link.list', array('associated', $id_of_your_configurable_product));

Basically my code is checking the type provided and if it’s “associated” it returns the child products.
I’m pretty sure there’s better way of doing it but I thought that the Product Link API was the most relevant place to do it.

Enjoy!

(please note: this code is not mine, i just adapted it and thought it would be a nice idea to help you guys out)